# Show that $Y\backslash f(X)$ is not compact

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Let $(X,\tau_X)$, $(Y,\tau_Y)$ be compact Hausdorff topological spaces, $f:X\to Y$ is an injective continuous map into $Y$, which is not surjective, and $f(X)$ is closed in $Y$. I need to show that $A:=Y\backslash f(X)$ is not compact. Can someone give a hint?

I know that a space is compact if for any open cover, there exists a finite open subcover. Since $f(X)$ is closed in $Y$, we know that $A$ is open in $Y$.

Here is my proof so far:
Assume that $A$ is compact. Then for any open cover there exists a open subcover. Any open cover of $Y$ is also an open cover of $A$, so any finite open subcover of $Y$ is also a finite open subcover of $A$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is not right. Take $X = \{1\}$ and $Y = \{1, 2\}$ (with the discrete topology) and let $f(1) = 1$. Then $Y \setminus f(X) = \{2\}$ is indeed compact. Where did you get this problem? Are you sure you copied it correctly? (Also, recall that a subset of a compact Hausdorff space is compact iff it is closed.)

Comment: In my exercise sheet, they used $X=S^1$, the unit circle, and $Y=T$ (torus). I thought that it would also work in the general case...) @SeanEberhard

Comment: I see. Try adding the hypothesis that $Y$ is connected.

Answer (score 1):

As shown by other comments it is false in general but if you just add to $Y$ to be connected you have a prove. Let $(X,\tau_X)$, $(Y,\tau_Y)$ compact not empty spaces Hausdorff, $f: X\to Y $ continuous and injective , $f(X)\not=\emptyset$ is closed in Y. $A:=Y\backslash f(X)$. Suppose by contradiction A is compact, then is also closed, because  Y is Hausdorff. By definition A is also open since is complementary to a closed set. So A is open and closed in Y, therefore is Y since Y is connected and by definition is the only closed and open set in itself. So $f(X)= \emptyset$.$\unicode{x21af}$